# Как задать css медиа-запрос и выстроить блоки в нужный ряд?

Tags: html, css

Имеется шесть блоков с картинками и текстом.

1. Как расположить на большом экране блоки в ряд 2 на 3?
2. Как задать @media и width, позиционирование, чтобы при уменьшении экрана (на мобильных устройствах) эти блоки шли не в ряд 2 на 3, а строго друг под другом?

```html
<div class="container custom-container works-wrapp">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="content-wrap">
   <div class="col-sol services-wrapp_item-block">
    <div>
     <a>
      <img src="/local/templates/brandspot/images/prod-promoface.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="hover-block">
                          <h3>Promo Face</h3>
                           <p>
                               Вспомогательная программа, позволяющая отслеживать<br>
                                  эффективность и осуществлять контроль<br>
                                  работы над промо-персоналом.
                              </p>
                          </div>
     </a>
    </div> 
    <div>
     <a>
      <img src="/local/templates/brandspot/images/prod-ky.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="hover-block">
                                <h3 class="small">Корпоративный университет </h3>
                                <p>
                                    Виртуальный портал для дистанционного обучения и
                                    развития сотрудников, а также для ознакомления
                                    со структурой и внутренним взаимодействием
                                    в Компании.
                                </p>
                            </div>
     </a>
    </div> 

    <div>
     <a>
      <img src="/local/templates/brandspot/images/3.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="hover-block">
                          <h3>Promo Face</h3>
                           <p>
                               
                              </p>
                          </div>
     </a>
    </div>

    <div>
     <a>
      <img src="/local/templates/brandspot/images/4.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="hover-block">
                          <h3>Test</h3>
                           <p>
                               
                              </p>
                          </div>
     </a>
    </div>

    <div>
     <a>
      <img src="/local/templates/brandspot/images/5.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="hover-block">
                          <h3>Test</h3>
                           <p>
                               
                              </p>
                          </div>
     </a>
    </div>

    <div>
     <a>
      <img src="/local/templates/brandspot/images/6.jpg" alt="">
       <div class="hover-block">
                          <h3>Test</h3>
                           <p>
                               
                              </p>
                          </div>
     </a>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а здесь кто то знает где этот нужный ряд ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Привет! Я блок, который будет занимать всю ширину родителя при разрешении экрана меньше 450 `px`, а на других экранах - треть ширины родителя!</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Привет! Я блок, который будет занимать всю ширину родителя при разрешении экрана меньше 450 `px`, а на других экранах - треть ширины родителя!</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Привет! Я блок, который будет занимать всю ширину родителя при разрешении экрана меньше 450 `px`, а на других экранах - треть ширины родителя!</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Привет! Я блок, который будет занимать всю ширину родителя при разрешении экрана меньше 450 `px`, а на других экранах - треть ширины родителя!</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Привет! Я блок, который будет занимать всю ширину родителя при разрешении экрана меньше 450 `px`, а на других экранах - треть ширины родителя!</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">Привет! Я блок, который будет занимать всю ширину родителя при разрешении экрана меньше 450 `px`, а на других экранах - треть ширины родителя!</div>
</div>
```

И где-то в вашем `css`:

```
.col-sm-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 49.9%;
}
.row {
  float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .col-xs-12 {
    width: 100%;
  } 
}
```

Таким образом, у вас получится два столбца, в каждом по три строки, согласно вашему комментарию. При любом разрешении экрана, больше 450`px` именно так они и будут следовать, а при разрешении меньше - будут занимать всю ширину родительского блока.

Comment: правильно, только я хотел 2 столбца и по 3 строки в каждом. т.е. поправить на 49,9, получается.